# BiwaScheme - Why does a parameterless function with call/cc in its body suddenly require a parameter when called?

Tags: scheme, continuations

Basic example tested on Repl.it:

```
; when foo is called, applies current context to value 25
(define foo (lambda ()
  (call/cc
    (lambda (k) (k 25))
  )
))
```

then

```
>>(foo)
[BUG] unknown opecode type: undefined []
>>(foo 'dummy)
25
>>(+ 10 (foo))
[BUG] unknown opecode type: undefined []
>>(+ 10 (foo '(d u m m y)))
35
```

As an actual example, copying the code of `tree-generator` and `same-fringe?` from http://ds26gte.github.io/tyscheme/index-Z-H-15.html#node_sec_13.1 gives the same error, which is fixed by replacing the calls `(gen1)` and `(gen2)` with `(gen1 'blah)` and `(gen2 'whatever)`.

Comment: It works in MIT/GNU Scheme. Like the message says, it's a bug in that Scheme implementation.

Comment: It works also in GNU Guile.

Comment: You may want to report your problem on BiwaScheme's issue tracker: https://github.com/biwascheme/biwascheme/issues